# AngularJS - Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Under controller folder, I have created CustomerController.js:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('CustomerApp').controller('CustomerController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'Sumit', age: 27, salary: 27000, address: 'Katwaria Sarai', joined: '2016-09-21'},
            {name: 'Ankit', age: 25, salary: 34000, address: 'Katwaria Sarai', joined: '2016-06-22'},
            {name: 'Kuldeep', age: 26, salary: 27000, address: 'Sangam Vihar', joined: '2016-01-21'},
            {name: 'Ashutosh', age: 27, salary: 27000, address: 'Vasundara', joined: '206-09-21'},
            {name: 'Rashid', age: 17, salary: 17000, address: 'Pune', joined: '2016-09-21'},
            {name: 'Shifali', age: 27, salary: 17000, address: 'Katwaria Sarai', joined: '2016-09-21'},
            {name: 'Anita', age: 27, salary: 19000, address: 'Katwaria Sarai', joined: '2016-09-17'},
            {name: 'Deepak', age: 27, salary: 29000, address: 'Mahipalpur', joined: '2016-09-15'},
            {name: 'Abhishek', age: 27, salary: 27000, address: 'Darjeeling', joined: '2016-09-19'},
            {name: 'Binetesh', age: 27, salary: 30000, address: 'Kishangar', joined: '2016-09-23'},
            {name: 'Devendra', age: 27, salary: 9000, address: 'Bangalore', joined: '2016-09-22'},
            {name: 'Himanshu', age: 27, salary: 15000, address: 'Sangam Vihar', joined: '2016-03-29'},
            {name: 'Parry', age: 27, salary: 12000, address: 'Siri', joined: '2016-01-07'},
            {name: 'Amit', age: 27, salary: 17000, address: 'Katwaria Sarai', joined: '2016-01-11'}
        ];
    });
}());
```

`
Under module folder I have a file app.js. The code is as follow:

```
 (function(){
     var CustomerApp = angular.module('CustomerApp',[]);
  }());
```

This is my index.jsp file that is described as follows:

```
<html ng-app="CustomerApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="sylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <title>Customer Page</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CustomerController">
<h2>Customer Data</h2>
Filter: <input type="text">
<br><br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
        <th>SALARY</th>
        <th>ADDRESS</th>
        <th>JOINED</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers">
        <td>{{cust.name | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.age | number}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.salary | currency}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.address}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.joined | date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="controller/CustomerController.js"></script>
<script src="module/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I  am using angular.js file with version 1.5.0

When I am running this code, it gives this as an error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'CustomerApp' is not available or its not loaded

Please help me out. I have tried a lot and still no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Load `app.js` before `controller.js`,

So that `CustomerAppmodule` angular module will be available for `controller.js` to extend module with controller component to `CustomerApp` module.

```
<script src="module/app.js"></script>
<script src="controller/CustomerController.js"></script>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/axjP7rJGzA15O1KOKyV2?p=preview)

Comment: Pankaj @ Thank you I have knew this concept but I forgot to placed Thank you so much

Comment: @sumit810 do [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).. if it does solved your problem. Thanks :-)